# Regex for converting object notation to array values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, replace

I am trying to convert objects defined within a file into arrays.

I am using `JSON.parse` on the matched objects.

Some of the multi-line objects are not being replaced.

```js
const txtara = document.querySelector('#demo');

const fixJSON = (invalidJson) => invalidJson
  .replace(/(\w+)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"') // Quote keys
  .replace(/,\}/, '}')               // Remove stray commas
  .replace(/,\n\s*\}/, '}');         // Remove stray commas (multiline)

const jsonObjectToArray = (jsonObject) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(fixJSON(jsonObject));
  return JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj));
}

let content = txtara.value
  // Inline object
    .replace(/(\{(.+)\})/g, (match, json) => jsonObjectToArray(json))
  // Multi-line object
    .replace(/(\{\s*\n(?:\s*\w+\s*:\s*.+,?\n)+\s*\})/, (match, json) => jsonObjectToArray(json));

txtara.value = content;
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#demo {
  flex: 1;
  resize: none;
  color: #EEE;
  background: #222;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo">
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>
```

Comment: Manually 'fixing' JSON is a fools errand. That being said will it always be a flat list of  objects with integer values?

Comment: @pilchard and possibly signed floating-point numbers.

Comment: **What  from** does that data comes?

Comment: If the data is TRUSTED SOURCE you can just use `eval`

Comment: You're missing the `g`  flag on the regexp for multi-line objects, so it will only replace the first match.

Comment: And the `s` flag will allow `.+` to match across newlines.

Answer (score 2):

If you need *only numbers*, then your answer is

```
function textToNumberArrays(text) {
  return text.match(/\{[^}]\}/g) // match {...}
    .map(obj => {
      return obj.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g) // match 123 and 123.456
        .map(n => Number(n)) // convert match strings to numbers
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to replace the text (rewrite) within the file. I used a modified version of your object matching expression in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your data seems to be written in [JSON5](https://json5.org/), a superset of JSON (i.e. valid JSON is also valid JSON5). It supports unquoted keys, trailing commas (one per array/object) and comments, among others.

That said, just get it from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5), [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/json5) or any other source of your choice and enjoy the simplicity it brings:

```js
JSON5.parse(data);
```

This is guaranteed to be safe: there's no `eval()` anywhere to be seen.

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  '{x:1,y:2}',
  '{x:1,y:2,z:3}',
  '{x:1,y:2,z:3,}',
  '{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }',
  `{
// A JSON5 comment
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  }`,
  `{
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }`,
  `{
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }`,
  `{
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3,
  }`
]

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  const parsed = JSON5.parse(testcase);
  const converted = Object.values(parsed);
  console.log({ parsed, converted });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json5/2.2.3/index.min.js" integrity="sha512-44jdhc+R2TFfzBflS3/dGNEABiNUxBkkrqwO7GWTvGsj3HkQNr3GESvI9PUvAxmqxSnTosR0Ij9y3+o+6J1hig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did not know about the JSON5 node module! Thanks. I included a modified version of your test snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and a sliding window that you expand whenever `eval()` throws an error.

Then, once you have parsed all objects, it's quite straight forward to turn them into arrays:

```
parsedObjects.map(({ x, y, z }) => [x, y, z].filter(n => n !== undefined));
```

Here's a complete example:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

const parseButton = document.getElementById('parseButton')

parseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const parts = textarea.value.split('\n');
  const parsedObjects = [];
  
  let from = 0;
  let to = 0;
  let n = 1; 
  
  while (from < parts.length && to <= parts.length) {
    try {
      to = from + n;
      
      const parsedObject = eval(`(${ parts.slice(from, to).join('') })`)
      
      parsedObjects.push(parsedObject);
      
      from = to;      
      n = 1;
    } catch (err) {
      ++n;
    }
  }
  
  const parsedArray = parsedObjects.map(({ x, y, z }) => [x, y, z].filter(n => n !== undefined));
  
  console.log(`${ parsedArray.length } objects found = `, parsedArray);
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 8px;
}

#textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  resize: none;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parseButton {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>

<button id="parseButton">Parse</button>
```

But keep in mind `eval` should only be used in trusted environments:

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use `eval()`.

See [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!).

Comment: I need to replace the content, so extracting the objects is only half the battle.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Just updated the answer with that part.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working four different ways. I included the two other solutions at the end. I modified the `<textarea>` value just to add a little noise, since the files to be rewritten may include more than just object definitions.

#### Extracting numbers, skip parsing

Here is my working solution that involves finding object-like expressions using a modified version of Dimava's expression `/\{[^}]+\}/gm`.

I used the following regex to match numbers: `/[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)/g`.

```js
const txtara = document.querySelector('#demo');

const rewriteObjectsAsArrays = (text) =>
  text.replace(/\{[^}]+\}/gm, jsonObjectToArray);

const jsonObjectToArray = (jsonObject) => {
  const nums = extractNumbers(jsonObject)?.map(n => +n);
  return nums ? JSON.stringify(nums) : jsonObject;
}

const extractNumbers = (str) =>
  str.match(/[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)/g);

txtara.value = rewriteObjectsAsArrays(txtara.value);
```

```css
*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0}body{display:flex}#demo{flex:1;resize:none;color:#eee;background:#222;padding:.5rem}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo">
// This is a comment...
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
const foo = 'bar'; // An expression...
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>
```

---

## Notable solutions

#### Dimava's modified solution

Using `JSON.parse` after fixing the objects.

- Find objects: `/\{[^}]+\}/gm` to
- Find trailing commas: `/,(:?\n\s*)?\}/`

```js
const txtara = document.querySelector('#demo');

const fixJSON = (invalidJson) => invalidJson
  .replace(/(\w+)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"') // Quote keys
  .replace(/,(:?\n\s*)?\}/, '}') // Remove stray commas

const jsonObjectToArray = (jsonObject) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(fixJSON(jsonObject)); // Fix and parse the JSON
  console.log('Converting object to array:', JSON.stringify(obj));
  return JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj));
}

txtara.value = txtara.value.replace(/\{[^}]+\}/gm, jsonObjectToArray);
```

```css
*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0}body{display:flex}#demo{flex:1;resize:none;color:#eee;background:#222;padding:.5rem}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo">
// This is a comment...
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
const foo = 'bar'; // An expression...
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>
```

#### InSync's modified solution

Using `JSON5.parse` after finding an object-like expression.

```js
const txtara = document.querySelector('#demo');

const jsonObjectToArray = (jsonObject) => {
  const obj = JSON5.parse(jsonObject); // Parse JSON-like object string
  console.log('Converting object to array:', JSON.stringify(obj));
  return JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj));
}

txtara.value = txtara.value.replace(/\{[^}]+\}/gm, jsonObjectToArray);
```

```css
*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0}body{display:flex}#demo{flex:1;resize:none;color:#eee;background:#222;padding:.5rem}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json5/2.2.3/index.min.js" integrity="sha512-44jdhc+R2TFfzBflS3/dGNEABiNUxBkkrqwO7GWTvGsj3HkQNr3GESvI9PUvAxmqxSnTosR0Ij9y3+o+6J1hig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<textarea id="demo">
// This is a comment...
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
const foo = 'bar'; // An expression...
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>
```

### Danziger's modified solution

Using `eval()`, but without the sliding-window. Eval should be safe, because only objects should be matched.

```js
const txtara = document.querySelector('#demo');

const jsonObjectToArray = (jsonObject) => {
  const obj = eval(`(${jsonObject})`); // Typically dangerous
  console.log('Converting object to array:', JSON.stringify(obj));
  return JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj));
}

txtara.value = txtara.value.replace(/\{[^}]+\}/gm, jsonObjectToArray);
```

```css
*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0}body{display:flex}#demo{flex:1;resize:none;color:#eee;background:#222;padding:.5rem}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo">
// This is a comment...
{x:1,y:2}
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
{x:1,y:2,z:3,}
{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
const foo = 'bar'; // An expression...
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
{
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}
</textarea>
```